# Переиндексация айдишников в таблице

Tags: mysql

У меня есть таблица с айдишниками, которые присваиваются автоматически при попадании в таблицу нового значения.

Когда я удаляю командой

> DELETE FROM `clientList` WHERE `id` = 'id';

у меня удаляется данная строка в таблице.
Могу ли я переиндексировать 'id' после выполнения данной команды, чтобы таблица была без дырок?

Comment: Сделать это возможно, но смысла в этом нет.

Comment: А зачем? Если удалить самого первого клиента, то изменятся id всех остальных и тогда потеряется смысл уникального идентификатора. А если ещё и связи в бд будут, то сломается всё

Comment: *переиндексировать 'id' чтоб таблица была без дырок* Крайне вредное желание. Но если оно непреодолимо - введите в структуру дополнительное поле (не уникальный индекс-автоинкремент, а простое поле), который и заполняйте в соответствии с этой хотелкой.

Comment: нужда отпала, просто вытягиваю данные с базы, и смотрю надо ли с ним работать.

Comment: Мы Вам об этом сразу и писали

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SET @t=0;
UPDATE `clientList` SET `id` = (@t := @t + 1);
```